# Using a Worksheet_Change target value that is a formula output not a manual input

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing code to clear the contents of a cell if another cell equals 2 different values. The first Target Range value is a formula pulling in the number from another sheet. The second target value is a manual input.

The second part of this code works, but not the first part. If I change the value in D9 to a manual input then the first part of the code works.

What do I need to change so it recognizes the value brought in from another sheet?

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D9")) Is Nothing Then
    If Target = 1 Then
        Range("D23").ClearContents
        Range("E23").ClearContents
        Range("F23").ClearContents
    ElseIf Target = 2 Then
        Range("D23").ClearContents
        Range("E23").ClearContents
        Range("F23").ClearContents
    End If
ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Range("D11")) Is Nothing Then
    If Target = 1 Then
        Range("E13").ClearContents
        Range("F13").ClearContents
        Range("E23").ClearContents
        Range("F23").ClearContents
    ElseIf Target = 2 Then
        Range("F13").ClearContents
        Range("F23").ClearContents
    End If

End If
```

Comment: Changes resulting from formulas do not trigger the `Worksheet_Change` event. You should try with the `Worksheet_Calculate` event.

Comment: fwiw, that will crash if a range of cells that includes either D9, D11 or both is changed.

Comment: @Jeeped good catch.

Comment: Is there a way to do the first IF Not  on a separate Sub just using if statements, since it won't recognize the D9 value?

Answer (score 0):

Intersect only gives you a value if the interactions is done in the range you insert:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Intersect(Target, Columns(1)) Is Nothing Then
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("D1").Value = "The active cell does NOT Intersect"
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("D2").Value = Target
Else
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("D1").Value = "The active cell does Intersect"
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("D2").Value = Target
End If
```

End Sub

if you want to take the range from another sheet you need to write: sheets("YOUR_SHEETNAME").Range("D11").

you are right now looking if the cell selected is cell D9 or D11 in one sheet